# How to add class to the currently clicked element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to add class to the currently clicked element?

Here is my HTML code-

```
<ul>
  <li class="ClickToActive"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li  class="ClickToActive"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#">service1</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">service2</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">service3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is my jquery code-

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ClickToActive').click(function(e){
      if ($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        var id=$(this).closest("li").children("ul").attr('id');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
      }
      var arr = id.split('-');
      var menu_id=arr[2];
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+menu_id).offset().top
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
```

when I click parent li only that element should be active and when I click to its child then that child also should be active.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: what i understood is if you click on child `li` or  parent `li`, in both case  parent `li` get `active` (active class get added to parent `li`). Am i right?

Comment: yes you are right but i want that when click on parent li then only parent get active  and when click on child li only it get active.

Answer (score 0):

when you click child element of class and you can add class to it like the following.

```
e.toElement.parentNode.classList.add("active");//e is the event
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ClickToActive').click(function(e){
      $('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
      e.toElement.parentNode.classList.add("active");
      //e.toElement.classList.add("active");
      //If you want to add class to current element(a tag). then try this
    });
});
```

```css
.active>a{
  background:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ClickToActive"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li  class="ClickToActive"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#">service1</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">service2</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">service3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m ha ha. just added that for fun. I'm unable to change it for 30 days